Up to a certain number of witnesses, say 4
For a language $L$ to be in $NP$ it suffices for a witness $y$ to exist and a (polynomial) verification algorithm $A$, s.t. $x\in L$ iff there exists a (polynomial size) $y\,$ s.t. invoking $A$ on $x,y$ returns true.
I have been considering several versions, in which the number of such witnesses is limited.
What if only $c$ such witnesses exists at most, for a certain constant $c$? I wanted to consider a not-too-hard and not-too-easy constant $c$, e.g. $c=4$. So the formulation of the complexity class I refer to is:
$x\in L$ iff there exists a verified $A$ for which there are at most $4$ witnesses $y_1,...,y_4$ s.t. $A$ returns true on $x,y_i$. That is, I provide an upper bound of $4$ on the number of possible witnesses. Additionally, at least one witness must exist, it is not possible to have no witnesses at all. At least $1$, at most $4$.
Obviously, if a language $L$ belongs to my complexity class, it belongs to $NP$ as well.
But I have been pondering: Can I claim more?
For instance, I am looking at the complexity class $\Sigma_2$. Can I claim my complexity class is contained within $\Sigma_2$? Or perhaps within $\Pi_2$?
My question is:
A. Is it contained in either $\Sigma_2$ or $\Pi_2$?
B. Is it actually a new definition, or is it equivalent to a known complexity class?
Side note:
I used $c=4$ because $c=1$ seems too hard to me and on the other hand I think any $c>4$ is equivalent to $4$. As for $c=2$ it might be too near to only a single witness ($c=1$). I could have chosen $c=3$, but I think $4$ and above is more intriguing.

Your title says "exactly", the body says "at most".  Please [edit] your post to make them consistent.

The case where $c=1$ corresponds to the class UP.

Yet it appears that the question still doesn't match what you actually wanted to ask.  It is challenging to deal with a question that keeps changing.  I encourage you to take more care in formulating questions in the future to make sure they accurately articulate what you want answered.

The question has been updated accordingly :-)

Your claim is wrong.  Such languages are not necessarily in NP.  NP is the class "has at least 1 witness".  CoNP is the class "has 0 witnesses" (equivalently: "has at most 0 witnesses").
Take a look at UP.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UP_(complexity), https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:U#up. Also take a look at US.  https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:U#us

Hey, I did mean at least 1, which makes the trivial case of no witnesses false, therefore my complexity class is a subset of $NP$.

@BenicioAgüero, I can only answer the question that was asked.  I can't read minds.

If i need four so-called “witnesses”, then these four “witnesses” together form one real witness.
If a problem in NP has an instance with an answer “YES”, then I solve this in two steps. 1. Hire a genius to find a witness. But assume the genius could be a scammer who gave you a false witness. 2. Check in polynomial time that the witness proves the answer is “YES”.
If a problem is not in P, then a witness cannot always be found in polynomial time: Otherwise you could let your genius look for a witness, but only for polynomial time, and if it doesn’t find a witness that would prove the answer is “NO”.

The question says "at most", rather than "at least" (though I do wonder whether the poster actually meant "at least").

I am not sure I get your point. Are you suggesting that any limitation on the number of witnesses cannot be an actual limitation, as one can simply concatenate these witnesses, thus creating new ones? If so, that is an interesting claim.

If so, I think that it is not true, as first a verifier must exist. My condition is for a verifier to exist s.t. for that verifier there is at least one witness and not more than $4$.
